# ASP.NET / WCF: Mapping JSON foreign keys back to their real objects

Tags: asp.net, wcf, json, entity-framework-4.1, deserialization

I have a WCF Webservice with a "Read" method that gives out a JSON-serialized list of Person objects. Each of these Person objects has a certain status, represented by a respective Status object. This gets mapped as a foreign key relationship by the Entity Framework.

Now, for the JSON output, I didn't want the Status of each Person to get serialized as a full nested object. Instead, I wanted the webservice to include a respective "StatusId". That is how I did it:

```
[DataContract]
public class Status
{
    public Status() {}

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DataMember(Name = "StatusId")]
    public int StatusId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class Person
 {
    public Person() {}

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [DataMember(Name = "PersonId")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Status Status { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "StatusId")]
    [NotMapped]
    public int JsonStatusId
    {
        get
        {
            if (Status == null) return -1;
            return Status.StatusId;
        }
        set {}
    }
}
```

And my webservice method looks as follows:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet]
public List<Person> Persons()
{
    return _dbContext.Persons.
        Include(person => person.Status)
        Select(person => person).
        ToList();
}
```

So far, that all works great. But when my WebApp sends an update request for one of the entities, I don't know how to map the StatusId back to a real Status object. In short: I get a JSON request containing an updated Person object with a changed StatusId. Is there a proper way to receive a Person object referencing the correct Status object?

Thank you all in advance,
Florian

Answer (score 0):

Your current solution is quite good, but I think you have a few options here, which means you may have to slightly change your existing solution.

- Serialize both Status and StatusId at all times. In other words, mark Status as a DataMember as well. I realize WHY you want to serialize only StatusId, but it will not increase processing time any more significantly if you also serialize Status. Clients that don't care about or understand Status can skip them altogether. This does increase the wire size significantly, because it's
- Use a deserialization callback (OnDeserializing / OnDeserialized) with an extension data object (IExtensibleDataObject, aka "extension data".) The idea is that you design the type such that any data the type doesn't understand (like Status info) would get deserialized into an "extension data bag". Your deserialization callback can examine this data and set Status, if it looks like it was present on the wire.
- Use a data contract surrogate (IDataContractSurrogate), so that Status objects can get translated back and forth to other types
- Use a data contract resolver (DataContractResolver) to resolve known types dynamically.

In addition to MSDN and Stackoverflow, I'd also recommend [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/03/14/wcf-extensibility.aspx) from a WCF team member; it describes all these serialization corner case extensibility points in detail very well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this:

```
[DataMember(Name = "StatusId")]
[NotMapped]
public int JsonStatusId
{
    get
    {
        if (Status == null) return -1;
        return Status.StatusId;
    }
    set {}
}
```

Just implement the set, something like:

```
[DataMember(Name = "StatusId")]
[NotMapped]
public int JsonStatusId
{
    get
    {
        if (Status == null) return -1;
        return Status.StatusId;
    }
    set 
    {
        var _dbContext= new entities()
        Status = _dbContext.Statuses.First(p => p.Id == value);
    }
}
```